# Where can I find remaining time for preview render completion in 2.8?

Tags: rendering

In 2.79, running a preview render would let me see how long it would take for me to complete a certain number of samples. This was useful for me as I would often times set my preview samples to a number that is approximately equal to how long I'll be away from the computer for, or for me to gauge how long a particular scene might render on a certain sample setting.

Now in 2.8, I only see this:

[image]

How do I get back that indicator?

Answer (score 0):

Change the way the render will be displayed in Render (Blender's header) > Display Mode > Image Editor.

[image]

Render again. Now see if a status bar appears inside Image Editor with the information you need.

[image]

---

To preview in `Render Preview` (Rendered Viewport Shading), enable `Overlays` and check the `Text Info` checkbox. Now the remaining samples will probably appear.

[image]

Comment: No change. Keep in mind, this is for a preview render, not a full render. That is, when you select `Rendered` for `Viewport Shading`. The full render already shows the correct information.